# Организация поиска контакта по подстроке

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Планирую небольшое веб-приложение типа записной книжки. Основной объект доменной модели - контакт с большим числом полей (ФИО, телефоны, емейлы, инстаграммы и жежечки). Хранится это в базе MS SQL.

Есть какой-то удобный способ указать какие поля индексировать (ну скажем, пара полей типа комментарии, город или номер карты сбербанка) и организовать поиск контакта по подстроке сразу по всем индексируемым полям?

> Пример. В окошке поиска набирают по буквам текст mar - и как только
>   число символов превысит два, то появятся варианты amarao (найдено в
>   поле никнейм), marat (найдено в поле ЖЖ) и так далее.

Никакого продвинутого поиска не нужно, только поиск по подстроке. Никаких "начинается с" или "заканчивается на" или "в поле фамилия то-то или в поле емейл то-то".

Пока вижу только вариант "перед сохранением в базу сохранять все данные в специальное поле для поиска".

Я когда думал о том, что не хочу доп. таблицы заводить под телефоны, телеграммы - а просто де/сериализовать в json и обойтись одним полем - готов был даже просто искать по одному этому полю, не создавая отдельное под индекс.

Возможно, есть какие-то другие способы?

На ум приходят слова типа Sphinx/Solr/Elasticsearch, но более детально не копался, т.к. в данном случае на сервере их нельзя поставить, да и не спец я по ним. SQL есть/будет, но не помню, в какие редакции входит полнотекстовый поиск и вообще поможет ли он.

Можно ли какой-то алгоритм использовать для построения индекса, чтобы не перебирать всю таблицу?

Comment: Полнотекстовый поиск вещь крутая, достаточно гибкая при этом. Отработайте гипотезу на нём, если невозможно по каким либо причинам - идите дальше. Берите отраслевые решения, аналогичная проблема ведь решалась и решается во многих продуктах. Свой велосипед выйдет дороже.

Comment: Никакой полнотекстовый поиск не найдет `amarao` по `mar`. Тут уже надо смотреть на ожидаемые размеры базы. При небольших планируемых объемах, проще будет смириться со сканом всей таблицы. При больших - придется придумывать что-то нетривиальное.

Comment: @Yaant База маленькая, полностью помещается в память. Объём таблицы контактов - счёт на десятки тысяч штук, не больше. Это ни о чём, но с учётом того, что крутиться отправлю на какой-нибудь дешёвое облачко - готов оптимальнее сделать, чтобы ресурсов поменьше жечь.

Comment: Тогда можно попробовать все нужные поля сконкатенировать в одно текстовое поле, и делать поиск по нему. Если скорость будет удовлетворительной, на том и остановиться. :)